# jquery sortable cannot read property 'top'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I build drag and drop system, but when i try sort elements i get error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
>       at e.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseDrag (jquery-ui.min.js:12:536)
>       at e.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseDrag (jquery-ui.min.js:6:7983)
>       at e.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseStart (jquery-ui.min.js:12:191)
>       at e.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseStart (jquery-ui.min.js:6:7983)
>       at e.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseMove (jquery-ui.min.js:6:15443)
>       at e.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseMove (jquery-ui.min.js:6:7983)
>       at HTMLDocument.n._mouseCapture._mouseDistanceMet._mouseDelayMet._mouseMoveDelegate (jquery-ui.min.js:6:14949)
>       at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3:6404)
>       at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3:3179)

In my html i getting a lot of 'block' divs, all empty.
My code:

```
$('#elements_Button').on('click', function(){
    var origin = 'sortable';
    //var $iframe = $('#courseBuilder_PageFrame');
    $('.card-element').draggable({
           helper: function(e) {
               return $('<div>').addClass('block').text($(e.target).text()));
           },
           containment:'body',
            iframeFix: true,
            connectToSortable:$('#courseBuilder_PageFrame').contents().find('.container').sortable({
                iframeFix: true
            }),
        //  revert: "invalid",
            start: function () {
                 origin = 'draggable';
             }
        });
    $('#courseBuilder_PageFrame').contents().find('.container').droppable({
        iframeFix: true,
        drop: function (event, ui) {
                 if (origin === 'draggable') {
                     ui.draggable.html(Course.getElementByName(ui.draggable.text()));
                     console.log(ui.draggable);
                     origin = 'sortable';
                 }
             }

        });
});
```

Html:

```
<div class="row block card-content card-element ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
<span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Header</span>
```

```
<div class="container ui-sortable ui-droppable">            
    <div class="row block card-content card-element ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: block;">
        <div class="col l12 m12 s12 header2">                   
        <h1 class="4s-editable">C-40Ai Aircraft</h1>                
    </div>          
</div>
....
```

here's jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/w9L3eorx/39/

i think my jquery version is not appropriate...

Comment: Do you have `.card-element` in your HTML? Show us your markup

Comment: Maybe a fiddle or codepen example would help?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use the latest version of jquery-ui v1.12.1.